# CSS Styling won't work in outlook 2010?

Tags: css, outlook, stylesheet

If I use styling in my outlook, it won't work.

how can I fix it? I am talking about this style code:

```
<div id="BodyID" Style=" word-spacing:2px;  min-width:0px; min-height:0px;max-width:693px; max-height:490px;  height:485px; background-color:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #e4e4e4; font-family:Arial;">
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately Outlook supports something roughly equivalent to IE5 compatible HTML.  It's *really* terrible.  Here's a detailed MSDN article on the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which I don't believe changed much for Outlook 2010.

Honestly, the only way I've been able to get outlook HTML to look the way I want is to hand generate the HTML using roughly HTML2 standard tags and properties and not using CSS at all.  Some CSS renders, but it's *really* hit or miss.

Comment: throw back to table based layouts all the way for emails

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this can help http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ It's a table, what is supported in E-Mails

---

edit
`min|max-width|height` not supported

Comment: If you want a layout in your Outlook mailing, than you **must** use HTML `tables`

Comment: @yunzen is correct, you need to use tables. Outlook 2010 - and presumably Outlook 2013 - doesn't support padding or margins on DIV or P tags, just on tables (TD basically).

Answer (score 4):

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

I've been using that as a base for my HTML email campaigns.

And the link yunzen posted to campaign monitor is a great resource.

Comment: great answer to the question behind the question.

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx) superlime linked to tells the sad story: for whatever incomprehensible reasons, Microsoft reverted nearly 10 years in their handling of HTML email w/Outlook2007, and did not see fit to fix it in 2010.

Having taken the trouble to design a well-formatted HTML layout for rest of the universe of mail user agents, I do see one saving workaround, which is what I'm going to direct my users to, rather than spend *my* time trying to reconstruct ancient HTML:

Use the **VIEW IN BROWSER** option Outlook offers for reading an email message. That re-assembles the HTML as intended.

Comment: Is there a way to create a link for the view in browser option? I've seen many emails that read "Click here if you're having trouble reading this email" but I always thought that just brought you to a copy on the website itself.

Comment: Good question. I wondered. And noticed that Outlook2010 on win7 doesn't ALWAYS give me that "view in browser" option above the message header info. Apparently it knows when it's screwing things up! [This fellow here](http://www.emailsignature.eu/phpBB2/how-to-get-view-in-browser-link-in-outlook-2010-t1550.html)
says you can at least ensure a recipient will get the option by
purposely putting in something outlook will break an empty, styled span: <span style="padding: 0px;"></span>

Comment: This will work: `#outlook a{padding:0;}`. It basically does nothing at all but forces outlook to display the "view in browser" link.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 3 columns table, click on the example link below.

Example: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yw29u5mk/)

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="400">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Content here...
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```